# Creating and updating dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
Date        Category         Value
1/1/2017    Cat1             111
1/2/2017    Cat1             222
1/3/2017    Cat2             333
1/4/2017    Cat3             444
```

How to convert it into dictionary of list of dictionary using category as key, list of dictionary [{date:value}] as value? e.g.

```
{cat1 : [{1/1/2017 : 111} , {1/2/2017 : 222}]}
{cat2 : [{1/3/2017 : 333}]}
{cat3 : [{1/4/2017 : 444}]}
```

How to append new dictionary element to the parent dictionary?

This data structure can then be used to plot multiple series scatter chart.

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers and comments. I tried Elisha's answer and it works perfectly. Here is the complete code to read in csv file and building the dictionary.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

input_file = "c:\\path\\to\\test.csv"

with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

formatted_content = csv.Dictreader(StringIO(content))

result = {}
for category, entries in groupby(sorted(formatted_content, key=itemgetter('Category')), key=itemgetter('Category')):
    result[Category] = [{entry['Date']: entry['Value']} for entry in entries]

print(result)

# continue processing the result to plot multiseries chart
```

Comment: What code have you written thus far?

Comment: @MikeTung Is Table is in any DB or in Text File?

Comment: @JoeHo What format is your data in?

Comment: how exactly is the data formatted? You have it nicely spaced in your example, but is that how if looks in your interpreter, a multi-line string?

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of python [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) functions:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

values = u'''Date,Category,Value
1/1/2017,Cat1,111
1/2/2017,Cat1,222
1/3/2017,Cat2,333
1/4/2017,Cat3,444'''

reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(values))


result = {}
for category, entries in groupby(sorted(reader, key=itemgetter('Category')),
                                 key=itemgetter('Category')):
    result[category] = [{entry['Date']: entry['Value']} for entry in entries]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use pandas you can do it this way:

```
df['DateVal'] = [{row.Date : row.Value} for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
df.groupby(by='Category')['DateVal'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Cat1': [{'1/1/2017': '111'}, {'1/2/2017': '222'}],
 'Cat2': [{'1/3/2017': '333'}],
 'Cat3': [{'1/4/2017': '444'}]}
```

- The first line creates a new column of dictionaries containing the Date as the key, and the Value as the value
- The second line groups items together by Category, generates lists of the grouped items, and spits them out as dictionaries.